# Django Selectmultiple

Tags: django, admin, multiple-select, django-widget

First of all, excuse for my english ^^

I don't understand how i can use the select multiple widget in django.
I mean, i don't understang which files and functions are necessary.

Example, I have two classes :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject=models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)
class Subjects(models.Model):
    sub_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And now, i want to use the select multiple widget, so which files and functions are necessary ?

I hope you understand what I'm asking ^^

Tks :)

Comment: `subject=ManyToManyField(Subjects)` should be:
`subject=models.ManyToManyField('Subjects')`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to have a `StudentForm` in models.py

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    subject = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Subjects.objects.all())
    #this would use widget 'SelectMultiple' by default

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ['name','subject']
```

if you want to use checkbox widget:

```
subject = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Subjects.objects.all(),widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

then in views.py:

```
class StudentFormView(View):

    form_class = StudentForm
    template_name = 'your_template.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('whatever_url_you_like/')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

in your urls.py add this:

```
url(r'url_to_your_form^$',StudentFormView.as_view())
```

in your_template.html add this in the body:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: what do you have now? Did you put your app in the settings.py? Did you syncdb? what error message do you have?